# AJAX PUSH (Streaming) implementation in Dojo and Java

Tags: java, ajax, dojo, streaming, push

I need to push data continuously from Java web application running on Tomcat to a Dojo implemented website.

How to handle this from both server and client?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Bayeux protocol. A stable implementation of this protocol is provided by cometd http://cometd.org/ (which is a Dojo Foundation project, and so it's fully compliant with dojo toolkit).

Comment: If the answer was useful pls accept it so that it goes out of the unanswered list.