# java tomcat6 - How to automatically refresh page when a data is added?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat6

first of all let me explain what Im tring to do. Im trying to create a very simple web based chat program. In my development I have 2 pcs using only 1 ip address. The ip address that is being used is the ip address which runs the tomcat6 server. The simple chat is connected to the database. How will I make the web page automatically update when the other pc input data(message) in the database without reloading the page.

Please forgive me if my question might sound idiotic. I have no experience in chat program. Please help.

Comment: you can use jms easily for write chat programs

Comment: @Sura How do you propose to use JMS in a browser without running into the same issue, namely the request/response nature of HTTP?

Comment: @pap Richfaces has inbuilt support for JMS messaging semantics, which includes guaranteed message delivery and push tech. See [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=push&sample=pushTopicsContext&skin=blueSky)

Answer (score 1):

What are the web technologies using there. If you are using JSF You can use AJAX Push feature from icefaces. you can read more from this link. http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/ajax-push.jsf

Comment: Im using Hibernate, Spring, jQuery, and Dojo.

Comment: This post may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074444/ajax-push-streaming-implementation-in-dojo-and-java

Answer (score 1):

Technologies you may want to check out:

- Ajax
- [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
- [Comet](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/WhatIsComet)
- [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

Comment: Im using Ajax (Dojo and jQuery).

Comment: then you can poll the server for new messages

Comment: How am I suppose to do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is overly broad, you should try something and ask questions regarding your problem; you can for example have a table called messages, then a servlet checking for new info in the messages table, when you make a request to that servlet it returns any new messages that it may or may not have found

Answer (score 1):

You can try webSockets. Its a new feature in html5. It allows you to do full duplex communication. Its very simple. You will have to do both client side and server side. For doing the server side you will need tomcat 7.0.32. It contains a new WebSocketServlet. 
These links may help you..

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/websocket/

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/

Comment: For some reasons I have to stick to tomcat 6. Is there an API that works similar to WebSocketServlet in tomcat7?

Comment: You will have to use polling/long polling/streaming...
Use ajax or comet